# Do the same in illustrator and photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator

So i made this logo in Photoshop:

https://p1.picsto.re/1nrtg.jpg

Is there any chance to do it in Illustrator? 
What i need is the "shiny glass" effect 
i made the rest already:

https://p1.picsto.re/kerdes1.jpg

the white shine part is almost okay (i can deal with it if i can't do the same)
but the black shadow part is always looking really bad

Comment: Is the "shiny glass" effect you're referring to what is showing as gradient sharp areas in the top right and bottom left areas of your PS composition?

Comment: Yes excactly i don't really how to call those parts
Or atleast to do a white (left top) and a black (right bottom) gradients

the black is always look really weak and i can't get the "feeling" what i get from the PS version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is to make the background consist one background plate (as you have done) and add the shiny glass as new layers on top of it (two different, since you have two shiny glass effects). To accomplish this - duplicate the background and alter it's shape so it gets the shiny shape 1 and add it on top of the background. Repeat and create the second shiny part.

You'll get the darker edges by applying an inner shadow (settings shown as picture 1A).

1. background

[image]

1A. Settings for background

[image]

2. shiny 1

The lighter borders has been done by changing from a dark inner shadow to a light.

[image]

3. shiny 2

[image]

4. complete

[image]

---

Get the AI file [here](http://speedy.sh/XBq8a/logo.ai).